# Coin Hive Captcha blocker Coin Hive Miner(CSS Selector)

Tags: html, css, api, css-selectors

I am having an issue with the CoinHive Miner being disabled by the captcha.

[Captcha Doc](https://coinhive.com/documentation/captcha)

[Miner UI Doc](https://coinhive.com/documentation/simple-ui)

```
data-disable-elements="input[type=submit]"
```

That is the line in captcha API that selects for a button. I would like to disable:

```
div class="coinhiver-miner"
```

Comment: So, what are you trying to do here? Have a Coinhive captcha be solved in order to unlock a Coinhive miner for use?

Comment: Yes exactly. The issue is once a page is loaded the minerUI can't be reloaded. Ended up with a hot fix that calls loading portion of their script